# Flask - Jinja2 not rendering placeholder (variable) in form input

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to render a placeholder of form input on my website. I'm using Python Flask including Jinja 2. I have a list of strings in the python script and I randomly select one to render using Jinja2.

It's name is cplace (variable). But when I use this variable in Jinja2 like {{cplace}}, it doesn't render the value. It only renders '{{cplace}}'.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import Form 
from wtforms import StringField
from random import choice
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length, AnyOf
import random
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'iamahnaf'



random_placeholders = ['What is Minecraft?', 'Minecraft VS Roblox', 'Why PUBG sucks..', 'Python VS C++', 'Bootstrap VS Semantic']



@app.route("/")
def hello():
    cplace = str(random.choice(random_placeholders))
    print(cplace)
    return render_template('index.html', cplace = cplace)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Ahnaf Zamil's Website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../static/images/favicon.ico" sizes="64x64">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="srch" name="search" placeholder={{cplace}}>
      <button class="hvr-radial-out" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

his lack of quotes to the placeholder. Try it.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="srch" name="search" placeholder="{{ cplace }}">
```